# Cloud Watch Agent stopped immediately

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-cloudwatch

After I started Cloud Watch Agent, it stopped immediately.
I would appreciate it if you could help me.
I already added IAM Roll and installed collectd.
(CloudWatchAgentAdminPolicy, CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy)

[OS]

-Ubuntu 18.04

[Command]

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
```

[Message]

****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******

/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader --output-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --download-source file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
Successfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json.tmp
Start configuration validation...
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-translator --input /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json --input-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --output /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default

2021/10/28 03:39:40 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json.tmp ...
Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
No csm configuration found.
No log configuration found.
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -schematest -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
Configuration validation second phase succeeded
Configuration validation succeeded
amazon-cloudwatch-agent has already been stopped

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.